# How to calculate total byte sent and received by a website using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm doing this but this is only in the case of GET and it also not giving correct output in Chrome.

```
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML 
      = parseInt(xhttp.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
```

Comment: You've not provided enough information to answer this question. What is `xhttp`.

Comment: xhttp is the object of XMLHttpRequest, but I'm not getting, can anyone explain it in jquery also.

Answer (score 0):

Content-Length returns the length of the request body in octets (8-bit bytes), That is why you are not getting the correct value.

[Refer This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Comment: The above one is using XMLHttpRequest(), and it is only working with get method. So, Can you explain the same question using jquery.